# What does AWT.GetDrawingSurface do?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, vtk, jawt

I'm on a project where I need to use vtk with Java and JavaFX. And to give VTK the correct canvas where it can draw, I was wondering what does the function GetDrawingSurface() do in the code below. awt is a JAWT object described in jawt.h from the jawt library.

It's in order to rewrite a Java class to give the C++ the correct canvas.

```cpp
extern "C" JNIEXPORT jint  JNICALL
Java_vtk_vtkPanel_RenderCreate(JNIEnv *env, jobject canvas, jobject id0)
{
#if defined(WIN32_JAWT_LOCK_HACK)
  int hash;
  WJLH_HASH_FUNC(env, canvas, hash);
  WJLH_lock_map[hash] = 0;
#endif

  JAWT awt;
  JAWT_DrawingSurface* ds;
  JAWT_DrawingSurfaceInfo* dsi;
  jint lock;

  // get the render window pointer
  vtkRenderWindow *temp0;
  temp0 = (vtkRenderWindow *)(vtkJavaGetPointerFromObject(env,id0));

  /* Get the AWT */
  awt.version = JAWT_VERSION_1_3;
  if (JAWT_GetAWT(env, &awt) == JNI_FALSE)
    {
#ifndef VTK_JAVA_DEBUG
    printf("AWT Not found\n");
#endif
    return 1;
    }

  /* Get the drawing surface */
  ds = awt.GetDrawingSurface(env, canvas);
  if (ds == NULL)
    {
#ifndef VTK_JAVA_DEBUG
    printf("NULL drawing surface\n");
#endif
    return 1;
    }

  /* Lock the drawing surface */
  lock = ds->Lock(ds);
  if((lock & JAWT_LOCK_ERROR) != 0)
    {
#ifndef VTK_JAVA_DEBUG
    printf("Error locking surface\n");
#endif
    awt.FreeDrawingSurface(ds);
    return 1;
    }

  /* Get the drawing surface info */
  dsi = ds->GetDrawingSurfaceInfo(ds);
  if (dsi == NULL)
    {
    printf("Error getting surface info\n");
    ds->Unlock(ds);
    awt.FreeDrawingSurface(ds);
    return 1;
    }

// Here is the win32 drawing code
#if defined(_WIN32) || defined(WIN32)
  temp0->Finalize();
  JAWT_Win32DrawingSurfaceInfo* dsi_win;
  dsi_win = (JAWT_Win32DrawingSurfaceInfo*)dsi->platformInfo;
  temp0->SetWindowId((void *)dsi_win->hwnd);
  temp0->SetDisplayId((void *)dsi_win->hdc);
  // also set parent id to avoid border sizes being added
  temp0->SetParentId((void *)dsi_win->hdc);
// use mac code
#elif defined(__APPLE__)
  JAWT_MacOSXDrawingSurfaceInfo* dsi_mac;
  dsi_mac = (JAWT_MacOSXDrawingSurfaceInfo*)dsi->platformInfo;
  temp0->SetWindowId(dsi_mac->cocoaViewRef);
// otherwise use X11 code
#else
  JAWT_X11DrawingSurfaceInfo* dsi_x11;
  dsi_x11 = (JAWT_X11DrawingSurfaceInfo*)dsi->platformInfo;
  temp0->SetDisplayId((void *)dsi_x11->display);
  temp0->SetWindowId((void *)dsi_x11->drawable);
  temp0->SetParentId((void *)dsi_x11->display);
#endif

  /* Free the drawing surface info */
  ds->FreeDrawingSurfaceInfo(dsi);

  /* Unlock the drawing surface */
  ds->Unlock(ds);

  /* Free the drawing surface */
  awt.FreeDrawingSurface(ds);

#if defined(WIN32_JAWT_LOCK_HACK)
  if (WJLH_init_check == 0)
    {
    WJLH_init_check = 1;
    }
  WJLH_lock_map[hash] = 1;
#endif
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured out by myself that it was returning information on the window manager use on the system.

It uses the `getPeer` function of java to get the right information and give it to the C code. So it is not possible to give where i want to draw because the javadoc tells clearly that it is computer specific and could not be rewritten.

Hopefully, the last VTK version (6.1.0) gives a new option to have VTK in JavaFX by using `vtkJoGLPanelComponent`. It's supposed to be lightweight I guess because the other option, `vtkJoGLCanvasComponent` is not working at all.